# Is there a way I can find out why I didn't get a certain academic position?

Tags: job-search

I'm applying for postdoctoral positions and when I get rejection letters there is no reason given. Is there any way I can tell if there are "red flags" in my application that are getting it shot down? My adviser has reassured me that there is nothing wrong with my application but after so many rejections I am not so sure...If there really is a simple reason, I would like to know so that I can remedy my application.

Comment: At what point in the process do you get these letters?

Comment: After the department has picked their candidates.

Comment: I don't know what the state of competition is right now for positions. Sometimes it is very fierce.

Comment: Some people say they sent more than 200 applications... Others said they only sent one - must have been the right day, feng shui or the correct amount of bribe :) Persevere and ask for feedback - some emplyers won’t bother sending any feedback though... Good luck.

Comment: I'm amazed they're bothering to send you rejection letters, many post-docs don't even do that, you just apply into the void and never hear back....

Comment: Science nowadays is _Hell on Earth_, overregulated by bureaucrats and shamanism techniques like "scientific measurements" which include "citations", "indexes" etc. Good thing Einstein did not have to measure anything except time-space intervals. He got rejected a lot, btw. Check his bio.

Comment: Can you give more details, like which field you are in? Postdoctoral position can mean totally different things depending on your field...

Comment: I'm in pure math

Comment: 80 applications and 3 interviews indeed does not seem normal for a postdoc position. Could it be a combination of your nationality and the country where you're sending applications (like, you're a non-US citizen living in the US or something along these lines)? Maybe you could try to apply for a few positions in another country, just to see if you get a more positive response?

Answer (score 7):

You haven't said how many applications you've submitted or whether you've had any interviews.  It's possible that you're just being unrealistic about how many applications it will take to obtain a position.

In the US, employers are reluctant to say anything about why an applicant was rejected because of the possibility that this information will be used against the employer in a lawsuit.  It's likely that the faculty involved in the hiring decision will be under instructions to not say anything about why applicants weren't chosen.

Furthermore, even if you could get one of them to talk off the record, the likely reason would be something like "other applicants were slightly stronger or were better fits for our needs."  The reason for this is that the academic job market in most fields is extremely competitive for job seekers, and thus most positions attract many (dozens or even hundreds) of very well qualified applicants.  You should not expect that your application will have better than a 1 in 20 chance of being selected for an interview.

If you're making to the interview stage but haven't gotten any offers, then it's possible that your performance in the in-person interviews has hurt your chances of getting the job.  However, you shouldn't conclude that until you've had several interviews with no offers.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have applied to >80 positions and got 3 interviews with no offers. In America they usually don't interview applicants for postdocs. How can I tell if it is the in-person interviews, or exactly what it is that I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You probably need to strengthen your credentials, or at least the way you present them.

Comment: I don't have recent hard data, but a few years ago I heard of a math TT job at an elite liberal arts college near a major city that got 800 applicants.  I expect some position has broken 1000 applicants.

Comment: Even if things are random and I have a 3% chance of getting a given offer, after 23 applications my chances of getting an offer (assuming everything is random) is >50%. After 50 applications my chances of getting an offer is about 80%. My adviser believes that I am a strong candidate and didn't anticipate that I would struggle to get a single offer.

Comment: I think 1% is more accurate than 3% for a competitive but not exceptional candidate.

Comment: Three interviews with no offers could just be bad luck or it could be that you're not interviewing well.  You might consider working with a career coach (someone with human resources experience and knowledge of academic careers) on your interviewing.

Comment: In a few months, after the candidates have been hired for the positions you interviewed for, you can most likely find out who they were and then see how their backgrounds compare to yours.

Comment: I'm a little afraid to say this, and it might be hard to tease out cause and effect, but it seems to me that most math postdocs go to candidates whose advisors have some connection to the hiring department. So it's not even random.

Comment: @ElizabethHenning The correctness of what you wrote about "some connection to the hiring department" depend a lot on how broadly one interprets "some connection". For example, a postdoc currently working with me had the connection that his adviser's adviser had  been a postdoc in my department somewhat more than 20 years ago. A postdoc whom we just hired, to start in September, has the connection that his adviser and I were visiting researchers at Microsoft. If you include such connections, then not only the successful but the unsuccessful candidates probably have advisers with connections.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Exactly this kind of connection, where you prefer a candidate whose advisor you know personally.

Comment: @AlexeyB. Note the last sentence in my previous comment. Most of the unsuccessful candidates in my area (the only area where my opinion counts) also have advisers whom I know personally. In other words, tenuous connections like these are so common that finding them in the case of successful candidates implies nothing about preferences.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Obviously I know nothing about your situation, but if you personally know the advisors of all your postdocs then this means exactly that you only hire people whose advisors you personally know.

Comment: @AlexeyB. If all the applicants are people whose advisers I know, then the people I hire (or, more precisely, the people I rank highly in my list of suggestions to the hiring committee) are people whose advisers I know.

Comment: @Andreas Blass: In your department is how it works that each faculty member makes an individual short list based on who interests them and then everyone meets and intensely debates who should make the short short list?

Comment: @Gradstudent Each area within the department (my area being logic) is asked for a list of the top five postdoc candidates in that area. These lists are produced in a discussion among the (tenured and tenure-track) faculty in the area. Then the department's executive committee (consisting of the department chair and six elected members of the faculty) decides which candidates get offers.

Comment: That could be the reason why I am struggling with getting offers. For every faculty member X there are a number of applicants whose research interests are more interesting to X than mine. Maybe what I am working on just isn't interesting enough.

Answer (score 3):

You do not have the right frame of mind. You are asking a question that doesn't have an answer. People who have positions to give don't need a reason to *not* give it to you. They need a reason to give it to you. When you ask, "why didn't I get the position?", most of the time, there is nothing meaningful to answer beyond "we gave it to someone else". These days, competition is so fierce that for any position, there is a dozen candidates that the university would be lucky to hire. A choice needs to be made. And since we are not robots, this isn't an entirely rational choice. Hiring someone is a very complex decisions with many variables; who is the "strongest" candidate depends on many different things, like the person's skills, whether the hiring party thinks that you will continue to do good research/teaching, whether your future colleagues think you will be pleasant to work with, etc. In the end, a hair can separate the top candidate from the next one, but the choice is binary. *C'est la vie.*

Comment: What can I do to be the most likely to be picked?

Comment: What are things that will convince the committee that I will continue to do good research?